# como acceder a un valor en un dict en python

Tags: python, diccionarios, clase, patrones-de-diseño, singleton

Cordial saludo...

Estoy estudiando patrones de diseño en python... en está vez lo hago con "Singleton" y me paso lo siguiente:

"Estoy guardando los objetos en un dict y guardan perfectamente pero no logro aceder a sus valores"

El código es el siguiente:

```
def singleton(cls):
    instances = dict()

    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in instances:
            instances[cls]= cls(*args, **kwargs)
        
        return instances

    return wrap  

@singleton
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, username) -> None:
        self.username = username


u1 = User('Juan')
u2 = User('maria')
u3 = User('Jose')

print("u1 == u2 ? :", str(u1 == u2))
print("u3 is u2 ? :", str(u3 is u2))

# Como se imprime el username?
print(u1.username)
```

Yo quiero aceder al username y no lo logro me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'username'

Alguien me puede explicar como hago para aceder a los atributos de User?

Comment: `return instances[cls]` en singleton para retornar la instancia (un objeto User) y no todo el diccionario.

Comment: caballero... Es usted un genio... muchas gracias :)

Comment: Mejor elimina la pregunta, ya que está resuelta.

Comment: @CandidMoe vas a dar la idea de que toda pregunta resuelta, incluso siendo util para otros lectores, debe ser eliminada

Comment: @DanteS. Es mi postura que si una pregunta se resuelve con un simple comentario, díficilmente será de utilidad para otros. Ahora, si tú haces una respuesta completa, blah, blah, ahí si vale la pena conservarla.

Comment: @CandidMoe No contradije tu postura. Lo que pasa que no quedó clara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un error en

```
return instances
```

Se está retornando todo el vector. debes de retornar el vector en la posición self

así:

```
return instances[cls]
```

Comment: Ahora acepta tu respuesta para terminar el proceso.